# How to process output from match function in jq?

Tags: jq

I'm using js tool to parse some JSONs/strings. My minimal example is the following command:

```
echo '"foo foo"' | jq 'match("(foo)"; "g")'
```

Which results in the following output:

```
{
  "offset": 0,
  "length": 3,
  "string": "foo",
  "captures": [
    {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 3,
      "string": "foo",
      "name": null
    }
  ]
}
{
  "offset": 4,
  "length": 3,
  "string": "foo",
  "captures": [
    {
      "offset": 4,
      "length": 3,
      "string": "foo",
      "name": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I want my final output for this example to be:

```
"foo,foo"
```

But in this case I get two separate objects instead of an array or similar that I could call `implode` on. I guess either the API isn't made for my UC or my understanding of it is very wrong. Please, advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script takes the string value from each of the separate objects with `.string`, wraps them in an array `[...]` and then joins the members of the array with commas using `join`.

I modified the regex because you didn't actually need a capture group for the given use case, but if you wanted to access the capture groups you could do `.captures[].string` instead of `.string`.

`echo '"foo foo"' | jq '[match("foo"; "g").string] | join(",")'`